# Stereo-calibration with virtual camera

Tags: opencv, math, stereoscopy

Considering a stereo system composed of a camera and a pattern projector (i.e. laser with Diffractive Optical Element to create a grid or other pattern), it should be possible to calibrate this system and get the fundamental matrix linking the projector to the camera.

The projector being considered as a second camera, with the grid (choice made for the sake of simplicity) line intersection set at specific points in the virtual grid image.

First question: Is that correct? (I think so, but Im not 100% sure yet).

Second question: How should I set the projector virtual image? Is there a specific setup that will make things easier?

More details, and my thoughts:
First question it will work, Im now 100% sure about it.

Now my virtual camera (laser + DOE) is a camera with an intinsic K = Identity, and the real camera has a intrinsic K' (obtained by any calibration alg.).

F is the fundamental matrix as:

```
 x(camera) =Fx(projector)
```

and

```
 F = K".R.[R'|t]*I'
```

with:

K": transpose of K'

R: the rotation matrix between the two "camera" and R' its transposed.

t: the translation matrix between the two "cameras"

I': the transposed of the Identity matrix.

Im I correct?

If yes, then by facing a surface with this system, shouldn't I be able to get distance and orientation of the surface relative to the camera system (by checking the square distance of the points of the pattern on the real image to the epipolar lines )?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is concept of Camera Calibration Method Based on Laser Ranging or other pattern displays. For example the Kinect functions by covering the space with a constant, predetermined pattern of infrared dots. So yes it is possible to calibrate system composed of a camera and a laser projector.

[image: Kinnect with IR emitter]

The relationship between the world coordinates of a target point P and the image coordinates (u,v) of its projective point p is:

[image: Relation between point img coord to world coord]

Where fundamental matrix is a 3×3 matrix which relates corresponding points between two views. 
`x'Fx=0.`